# How do I define members of structure variable with an initialization list if there are more than one array of structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
struct Birthdate {
int Month;
int Year;
int Day;
};

struct Pet{
int ID;
Birthdate date_of_birth; 
int age;
string gender;
bool status;
}; Pet Information[10];     //Number of Pets whose information are needed


Pet Information[0]={ 1, 4, 2016, 28, 3, "Male" , false  };  //Conflicting declaration 'Pet Information[0]' occurs.
```

Can you not define variable with an initialization list like this?

Also, can I define bool value for status within the initialization list?

Answer (score 0):

You've already declared that `Information` is an array of `Pet` objects. You don't need to declare it again for each element. Just remove `Pet` from that line.

```
Information[0] = {1, 4, 2016, 28, 3, "Male", false};
```